# Is it possible to create a Single Page App consuming a bundled component library without installing it via npm?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, svelte, vite

I want to create a single page application using either React, Vue or Sveltekit ( other suggestions for tools that get the job done are welcome! ). This SPA will be embedded inside an iframe provided by an external system. The SPA calculates a dynamic table based on a configuration file. The configuration file tells the SPA which cell renderer to use for each column cell.

There are many cell renderers provided by default but there are some customized cell renderers only a few customers want to use ( and willing to pay for it ) . I don't want to have a directory e.g. `/renderers/core` and `/renderers/custom` and later contains a highly customized component like *RainbowCellRendererForCustomerFoo*

I would prefer a separate repository ( or Monorepo ) for each cell renderer and consume them in the SPA. But I don't want to install all the custom renderers via npm because I only want to ship the necessary ones. During configuration ( before running the CI pipeline ) we know

- which cell renderers are needed
- everything is using the same technology, Vite + e.g. Sveltekit

So we have 1 - n bundles of cell renderers and want to create a bundle for the main app. Is it possible that this main app is able to consume the cell renderer bundles during runtime? If not, is it possible to "inject" the cell renderer bundle into the main app bundle inside the CI pipeline?

- I don't know if it's important that the main app and each cell renderer share the same app instance
- I want to pass through props to the components and if possible also communicate with the cell renderers ( via function props, events, ... ) because some of them might provide some action buttons for example

I think I'm looking for something like a plugin system. I don't know if web components might help, never tried them. I hope this is more a Vite based question, regardless of the web framework.

I thought about "merging" the custom cell renderers into the main app during bundle time. I think the only way to do that is to install the components inside the CI pipeline and hope that Vite picks them up, although they aren't used inside the main code.

Do you have any ideas? Please let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Libraries were bundled with applications before Node.js was invented, so I have to assume the answer to your question is 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the plugin system using [webpack module federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/). WMF allows you to connect remote bundles during the runtime of the main app. It doesn't depend on any framework, so you can use the one you want. Moreover, WMF has [the repo](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples) that illustrates how it can be used with different frameworks (and Vite support)

Comment: thanks for this suggestion! Was hoping for a Vite bundle step to merge external components into the bundle

Comment: I provided a solution working for my case, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095020/19698303

Comment: @baitendbidz it's a pretty straightforward solution and has some drawbacks. The main drawback is that the host can't share its package dependencies (such as vue itself) with remote bundles. If your app will depend on only one remote bundle at a time, this is acceptable, but otherwise it may cause a performance issue

Comment: you mean like Vue instance, global state, ... ? I think props + events are sufficient for these components

Comment: I mean the whole Vue library. Each bundle has its own library baked into it. In other words, client browsers will download it at least twice to render your web app

Comment: With module federation, you can share such libraries between several bundles: the host & remote plugins

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it for my case but I will have to publish each customized component library to our private npm registry.

For the sake of simplicity I will show example code using VueJs and the component library https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons

I created a new Vue app and replaced the code inside App.vue with

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const myComponent = ref<unknown>(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  myComponent.value = defineAsyncComponent(async () => {
    const components = await import("@heroicons/vue/24/solid"); // library path coming from configuration file

    return components['CheckIcon']; // target component name coming from configuration file
  });
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>See component below:</div>
  <component v-if="myComponent" :is="myComponent"></component>
  <div v-else>-</div>
</template>
```

Please keep in mind that this is just an example. The paths and component names are coming from a configuration file. So this code would not build during development.

Inside the CI pipeline I just have to make sure I install all the required component libraries ( @heroicons/vue for this case ) **before** building the application and providing a distribution ( e.g. by reading configuration input and looping through it ).